# PHP use Version-Tag from npm, composer, bower, git

Tags: php, json, git, gruntjs, versioning

Is there a clever way of getting the current version of code (e.g. `2.3.1`) from either the .json-Files from `npm`, `bower` or `composer`, or the latest `git tag` in `php`? The solution should work with `grunt-bump`.

Parsing the .json-Files seems overkill for simply presenting the current version.

I tought of a `version.json` containing nothing but

```
    {
       version: 2.3.1
    }
```

but that (again) seems overkill.

If there aren't any solutions with the use of `grunt-bump`, are there any to increment the Code-Version in a class constant or a `.php` file?

Comment: `json_decode(file_get_contents("/foo/bar/baz.json"))` is overkill?

Comment: I think I will change from a `config.php` to a `config.json` (and adding the version there), then there is no additional file to read. This seems to be the most efficient + easy to use with grunt-bump.

Answer (score 0):

In git, versioning is generally accomplished by creating tags. The git [documentation of tagging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging) shows how to use it with semantic versioning ([spec 2.0 here](http://semver.org/)). I'm not certain, but I believe composer uses the git tags for semantic versions, while `dev-master` is always the latest commit.

To retrieve the latest versions of composer-installed packages you can parse the output from composer.

```
$installedPackages = `composer.phar show -i`;
```

To retrieve the latest tagged versions of your project in git you can parse the output from `git tag`. You probably are interested in a specific range, for example v2.* to retrieve the entire version 2 tags, like this:

```
$currentVersionTags = `git tag -l 'v2.*'`
```